# "Taking the temperature" of MP&T participation

Tags: discussion

A cardinal guideline across all SE sites is the dictum to "be nice" in one's comments and responses. Based on my limited time on *MP&T* it would appear that participants to this site are in compliance with that policy but appearances can be deceiving.

One way to "take the temperature" of *MP&T* as suggested in the query title would be to release information wrt to "negative behaviors." Obviously the question then becomes how best to define and measure "negative behaviors." The next question concerns the time frame for any reporting, e.g., past month? past year? since site inception?

If I were to choose a single metric for "taking the temperature" of the site it would be to summarize the number of comments that have been "flagged" for not *being nice* and break that down by reputation segment including collapsing some of the bigger segments down to 2,000+ to maintain privacy:

[image]

This question is probably best answered by the site moderators but the opinions of other participants are, of course, welcome.

Comment: Is there actually a "not nice" flag reason?

Comment: no - but there are ones like Rude and Abusive, Spam or Nonsense...

Comment: I'd say people are nice here. (Well, obviously not *that* nice - this is Stack Exchange, after all.) I do think your metric would be interesting, but probably more interesting if done officially across the full set of sites - and I doubt this particular metric would throw up any problems with this site.

Answer (score 5):

Three things here:

1) Taking the temperature by gaining information related to flags, despite having no current reason to think there is a problem strikes me as just going hunting for a problem that doesn't exist

2) Your view that taking the temperature would be best served by counting flags is interesting - can you explain why you think that would be a good measure.

and

3) No - we are not at liberty to release information like this

Comment: Thanks for your response even though I think you may have missed the point of my query. This is not a fishing expedition but rather is a reflection of real analytic interest. While you may very well be correct that the "problem doesn't exist," to Topo Morto's comment above *MP&T* cannot be considered exempt from normal human behaviors. Obviously a full suite of metrics reflecting positive as well as negative behavior would be ideal, in picking just one I was hoping to simply things. That said, I don't understand why the release of such information would be problematic.

Comment: Hi @DJohnson - I didn't at any point say I don't think the problem exists. You did, hence my comment. There are all sorts of metrics, but moderators are not at liberty to share them.

Comment: @DJohnson there are plenty of metrics for the site on Stack Exchange Data Explorer that is public information. Flagging behaviors and which users were flagged even at that rep level however are private data that we cannot release.

Comment: @dom  Good to know about this site. Thx.